# Filter arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection where each document contains 2 arrays of documents as below.

```
{
  all_users:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:"A"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"B"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:"C"
    }
  ]
  selected_users:[
    {
     id:1,
      name:"A"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"B"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to merge the 2 arrays by adding a field `selected` and assigning a value to it based on whether the name of the user is present in a document in the `selected_users` array as follows.

```
{
  all_users:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:"A",
      selected:"yes"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"B",
      selected:"yes"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:"C",
      selected:"no"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check by `id` or `name` since the documents may contain additional fields. I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `all_users` array
- `$cond` check condition if `id` is in selected users `id` then return "yes" otherwise "no" in `selected` field
- `$mergeObject` to merge current user object with above `selected` field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      all_users: {
        $map: {
          input: "$all_users",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                selected: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $in: ["$$this.id", "$selected_users.id"] },
                    "yes",
                    "no"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wMwrdtuw_cV)

Comment: Thank you! It works. If I had to project, say, only `name` and `selected` fields, what changes would have to be made?

Comment: you can simply return your needed fields see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iWffPXE8yCf)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Robo Mongo 3T, you can use JavaScript, so you can do something like that:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(doc => {
    doc.all_users.map(au => {
        const su = doc.selected_users.find(su => su.id === au.id);
        au.selected = su === undefined; 
    });
    delete doc.selected_users;
    db.collection.save(doc);
 })
```

I would advise you to create a Backup of the collection beforehand. :)