# Merge arrays by matching similar values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is an extension of the below question.

[Filter arrays in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819994/filter-arrays-in-mongodb)

I have a collection where each document contains 2 arrays as below.

```
{
  users:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:"A"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"B"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:"C"
    }
  ]
  priv_users:[
    {
      name:"X12/A",
      priv:"foobar"
    },
    {
      name:"Y34.B",
      priv:"foo"
    }
  ]
}
```

From the linked question, I learnt to use `$map` to merge 2 document arrays. But I can't figure out to match `users.name` to `priv_users.name` to get below output.

```
{
  users:[
    {
      id:1,
      name:"A",
      priv:"foobar"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"B",
      priv:"foo"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:"C"
    }
  ]
}
```

`users.name` and `priv_users.name` don't have a consistent pattern, but `users.name` exists within `priv_users.name`.
MongoDB version is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be as generic but will push you in the right direction. Consider using the operators [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) to merge the filtered document from the `priv_users` array with the document in users.
Filtering takes the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) of the `priv_users` name field and compares it with the `users` name field. The resulting pipeline will be as follows

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': { 
        'users': {
            '$map': {
                'input': '$users',
                'in': {
                    '$mergeObjects': [
                        {
                            '$arrayElemAt': [
                                {
                                    '$filter': {
                                        'input': '$priv_users',
                                        'as': 'usr',
                                        'cond': {
                                            '$eq': [
                                                '$$this.name',
                                                { '$substr': [ 
                                                  '$$usr.name', 4, -1 
                                                ] }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                0
                            ]
                        },                        
                        '$$this'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

---

If using MongoDB 4.2 and newer versions, consider using [`$regexMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) operator for matching the `priv_users` name field with the users name field as the regex pattern. Your [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator now becomes:

```
'cond': {
    '$regexMatch': { 
        'input': '$$usr.name', 
        'regex': '$$this.name', 
        'options': "i" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is is possible to check if one is substring of another or regex match `$$this.name` and `$$user.name`?

Comment: Yes, using [`$regexMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) which is available in MongoDB 4.2 and newer versions